# Mac OS X check if flash is installed

Tags: macos, cocoa, plugins, webview

My Mac OS X application opens a webpage via a WebView that requires flash.  If the user does not have flash installed I would like to give them a popup telling them to please install flash.

Is there a way to check the webview if the flash plugin is installed?  In WebPreferences you can enable/disable PlugIns but I can't find a way to query the currently install/enabled ones.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 5):

You may be able to write some JavaScript that does the checks and execute it through the WebView's window object.  To do this you'll need to read up on JavaScript's `navigator` object, specifically `navigator.plugins`.

Answer (score 2):

1. You can check the installed Flash version via a shell command: `/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c 'Print CFBundleVersion' /Library/Internet\ Plug-Ins/Flash\ Player.plugin/Contents/Info.plist`
2. Apple has provided [JavaScript code to detect plugins on a variety of browsers](http://developer.apple.com/internet/webcontent/examples/detectplugins_source.html). If you include this file, the following can be used redirect either to the Flash site or to your popup: `detectFlash("http://www.site.com/flashcontent","http://www.site.com/noflash")`
3. Per @Brian Kyle's excellent suggestion, it is possible to check for Flash in navigator.plugins:

```
var pluginCount = navigator.plugins.length;
for(var i = 0; i < pluginCount; i++){
  if(navigator.plugins[i].name=="Shockwave Flash") {
    document.write("Flash version " + navigator.plugins[i].version);
    break;
  };
};
```